# Upload File using Vue axios and Django Python Backend

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, axios

I have VueJs as my front end where i have upload component and using formdata to create request and axios to make rest api call to backend written in Django Python.

My Front upload method looks like:

```
uploadFiles() {
  if (!this.currentFile) {
    this.message = "Please select a file!";
    return
  } else {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.currentFile);
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: "<URL>",
      withCredentials: false,
    });
    instance
      .post("/test/", formData, {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Success!")
        console.log({ response })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log({ error })
      })
  }
},
```

Now backed micro service is Django Python where I want to use the file. However i am not getting the file here.

Code looks like below

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def attachment(request):
  myFile = request.FILES
  myfile2 = request.data.initial_data
```

i tried above two ways to extract files from request object but no success, however it works if i send request via postman.

Comment: when i am doing request.body, its giving me bytes like 

b'------WebKitFormBoundaryeLyU6scm9zAftfdU\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"\r\n\r\n[object File]\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryeLyU6scm9zAftfdU--\r\n'

What i am looking for though is MultiValueDict to use

Answer (score 0):

If it works using postman, you might want to compare the headers being sent from Postman and your frontend. Use request.META in django to see what is different.